# What's the quickest way to compare a NSUInteger with an int (e.g. 5) in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, ocunit

What's the quickest way to compare a NSUInteger with an int (e.g. 5) in objective-c?

Background - I'm noting that the following line of code gives an error:

```
STAssertEquals([nsMutableArrayInstance count], 5, @"xxxx");
// gives Type Mismatch
```

So what I'm asking effectively is how to correct this to fix the error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSUInteger i = 42;
int j = 5;

if (i > j) {
  NSLog(@"the universe has not ended yet");
}
```

Instead of using `STAssertEquals`, you could use `STAssertTrue`:

```
STAssertTrue([nsMutableArrayInstance count] == 5, @"xxxx");
```

Comment: You should also just be able to do `STAssertEquals([nsMutableArrayInstance count], (NSUInteger)5, @"xxxx")`.

Comment: The problem with the `STAssertTrue` is that when it fails, it won't say what the actual value was.

Comment: I encourage using `5U` as @JonReid suggests.

Answer (score 50):

`STAssertEquals` requires that you compare like types to like types. So add "U" to the number to make it an unsigned literal:

```
STAssertEquals([nsMutableArrayInstance count], 5U, nil);
```

Alternatively, you could use OCHamcrest to say:

```
assertThat(nsMutableArrayInstance, hasCountOf(5));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
STAssertEquals([nsMutableArrayInstance count], (NSUInteger)5, @"xxxx");
```

`(NSUInteger)5` does not look as clean as `5U` but it will also work correctly when compiling for 64-bit.